# How to print output to look like stairs?

Tags: shell-script, echo, for, printf

My code is this in my shell script file:

```
for i in {0..3}
do 
     COLOR_Value="\033[1;3"$i"m \t Hello World"
     echo -e $COLOR_Value
done
```

The output is this: (Each Hello World changes color as it reprints each line)

```
     Hello World 
     Hello World
     Hello World
```

I want it to do THIS:

```
Hello World
     Hello World
          Hello World
```

What changes can I make to get the output I want?

Comment: Looks like a possible homework question. Note that your `for` loop assigns a number from 0 to 3 to variable $i on each pass through the loop. For the first line, you want 0 spaces before the Hello World, 1*5 spaces on the second, 2*5 on the third... does this give you any ideas at all?

Comment: I know that, but when i try that it just tabs every iteration once, so i'm confused why the code wont increase the space every loop

Comment: Well, the attempt you posted clearly only changes the color on each iteration. So what exactly did you try to add an increasing number of spaces? (Please edit your original question instead of supplying additional information in the comments.)

Comment: Thats what I tried but clearly that's not it ^

Comment: The `$i` is the only part that will change in your COLOR_Value string, and it is in the middle of an ANSI code that determines the color of the output. After the code, there is a constant string "<space><tab><space>Hello World", which will be the same on every line. You'll need to calculate the number of spaces or tabs you'll need on the line using the current iteration number, then produce a string with the necessary number of spaces. Google for "shell Print a specific number of spaces", for examples.

Answer (score 3):

Use `printf` in the `bash` shell with an appropriate string width:

```bash
string='Hello World!'
for i in {0..3}; do
    width=$(( ${#string} + i*5 ))
    printf '%*s\n' "$width" "$string"
done
```

This uses the `printf` placeholder `%*s` which means "a right-justified string of the width specified by the next argument".  The width is calculated as the length of the string plus `i` times 5.  This means that you get 0 extra spaces in front of the string in the first iteration, 5 in the 2nd, 10 in the 3rd, and 15 in the last iteration.

With colours:

```bash
string='Hello World!'
for i in {0..3}; do
    width=$(( ${#string} + i*5 ))
    tput setaf "$(( i + 1 ))"
    printf '%*s\n' "$width" "$string"
done

tput sgr0  # reset colors
```

or with the color changes as part of the string that `printf` is outputting (resetting after each string):

```bsh
string='Hello World!'
color_reset=$( tput sgr0 )

for i in {0..3}; do
    width=$(( ${#string} + i*5 ))
    color=$( tput setaf "$(( i + 1 ))" )
    printf '%s%*s%s\n' "$color" "$width" "$string" "$color_reset"
done
```

Running it:

```
$ bash script.sh
Hello World!
     Hello World!
          Hello World!
               Hello World!
```

[image]